# Can this Encryption/Decryption Code work on Windows phone 7

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-7

Hi
Have use this code before. Find it useful on Web. But Dont know how to convert it for wp7. Will some1 take a shot at it?

```
script language="JavaScript"

 len=0; 

 function CalcKey() 
 {

    len=0; 
    var temp=document.Encrypt.Key.value; 

    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++) 
    { 
    len=len+temp.charCodeAt(i); 
    }


    if(len==0) 
    { 
    alert('Please Enter the appropriate Key'); 
    document.Encrypt.Key.focus(); 
    }

    return len; 
 }





function Encryption() 
{

    CalcKey(); 
    document.Encrypt.Encrypted.value=""; 
    var txt=document.Encrypt.normal.value;

    var net=""; 
    var fin=0;

    if(len>0) 
    {

      if(txt.length>0) 
      {

         for(i=0;i<txt.length;i++) 
         { 
           fin=txt.charCodeAt(i)+len;  
         if(fin>99) 
         { 
             net=net+fin;  
         } 
     else 
     { 
      net=net+'0'+fin; 
      }

      } 
       document.Encrypt.Encrypted.value=net; 
       document.Encrypt.normal.value=""; 
     } 
     else 
     { 
      alert('Please Enter the Text to be Encrypted'); 
       document.Encrypt.normal.focus();
      }  
    } 
 }



function Decryption()

{

var txt=document.Encrypt.Encrypted.value;

var j=3; 
var temp1; 
var res="";


CalcKey(); 

if(len>0)

{

if(txt.length>0)

{

for(i=0;i<txt.length;i+=3)

{

var temp=txt.substring(i,j); 
temp1=(parseInt(temp)-len); 
var t=unescape('%'+temp1.toString(16));

if(t=='%d' || t=='%a')

{ 
res=res+' ';

} 
else

{ 
res=res+t

} 

j+=3;

}

document.Encrypt.normal.value=res; 
document.Encrypt.Encrypted.value="";

}

else 
{

alert('Please Enter the Encrypted Text');

document.Encrypt.Encrypted.focus();

}

}

}
```

Comment: What does it do? - There may be a better way of solving the problem. What happens when you run it on WP7? Have you not tried converting it yourself? Are you trying to get this javascript running on WP7 or are you wanting to port it to another language? If so which?

Comment: @Matt Lacey: This is for creative communication with simple encrytion. Say, if you want to send a secret word, it will become a string of number. The recipient will need a Key from you to decrypt it. Why use this? because it cost less SMS as it only increase 10 to 20% after conversion of the original message. Hope some1 can try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this code simply escapes/unescapes text from a form like "HelloWorld" to some kind of integer shifted by its current position.

You can definitely port this algorithm across to C# - you'll need to use

- some kind of ((int)c).ToString() in order to write
- Char.ParseInt to read bits of the string back in

Alternatively there are existing encryption methods you can use - http://robtiffany.com/windows-phone-7/dont-forget-to-encrypt-your-windows-phone-7-data

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank for the tips. I wanted to use this because it cost less SMS when sending. Hope some1 can help to convert it in C#. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you need is a simple cipher or form of symmetric encryption.

Have a look at the [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) encryption algorithm.

Comment: ThankQ. Will check it out and report back later.